# Nginx with node app with existing application

Tags: nginx, node.js

I am completely new to nginx and I am trying to set something up so that it is possible to navigate from an existing application on a remote server to a node application. The node app will be on the same server. For now, everything is local on my own machine and I have fired up a simple nginx instance with it's default index page, i.e., navigating to `https://localhost` will render the default `Welcome to Nginx` page. I would like to be able to navigate to my node app with `https://localhost/app`, where the `app` part of the url is just an alias. There is no `app` directory in reality. Is this possible?

Currently if I run `localhost:3000` in my browser, it will redirect to `localhost:3000/login` if the user is not authenticated. Therefore `https://localhost/app` should also redirect to `https://localhost/app/login` and so on. I just cannot get this to work as I'm getting 404s with the server trying to request static resources with `app` in the uri i.e, `.../public/app/css`. It should be `.../public/css`. Same for js and images. So obviously my alias is not working. My config is as follows:

```
upstream nodeapp {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    include snippets/snakeoil.conf; # Temp cert for testing

    location /app/ {
            alias /home/path/to/public;
            proxy_pass http://nodeApp;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
            proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    }
```

I have looked at lots of similar questions and tried various configurations, but I'm completely out of ideas now. Any help would be most appreciated!

EDIT: if I add a slash to the end of proxy_pass `proxy_pass http://nodeApp/;` It redirects to `localhost/login` where I get a 404 as obviously there is no page set up there. Would I really have to add a location for every route in my node app? There must be a way of doing this. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect problem can be easily solved with the [proxy_redirect](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive:

```
proxy_redirect http://nodeApp/ /app/;
```

or more easily:

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://nodeApp/;
    proxy_redirect default;
    # rest of directives
}
```

However this will be the first of the problems you'll encounter with incorrect `URL`s: the links generated by your application, which use absolute paths, will lack the `/app` component. The easiest solution to this problem is to deploy your application at `http://localhost:3000/app` by tweaking the [Express Router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Redeploying to `localhost:3000/app` was the fix here. Makes sense! Thanks again!